# Find min of 3 numbers hardcoded

Tags: java

```
public static int min(int a, int b, int c)
{
    int result = 0 ;
    if( a < b && a < c && b < c) result = a ;
    else if( a < b && a < c && b > c) result = a ;

    else if( a > b && a < c && b < c) result = b ;
    else if( a < b && b  > c &&  c < a) result = c ;

    else if( a > b && b < c && a > c) result = b ;
    else if( a > b && a > c && c < b) result = c ;
    return result ;
}
```

Is it better than nested `if` statements?  Is there a **more readable solution** than this? To me it looks pretty readable, but I'm not sure whether it can be improved.

Comment: If if and and and *look* readable to you, try reading the code outloud. In before buffalo buffalo buffalo and james while john.

Comment: Just something minor but you can simplify this `a < b && a < c && b < c` to `a < b && b < c`.

Comment: It's hard to evaluate this without more context.  Is there a reason you're avoiding Math.Min?  Are you trying to optimize the number of comparisons?  Are you sure you won't need to handle 4 inputs?

Comment: your condidions are pretty complex. Why not do something like `int result = a; if(b < result) result = b; if (c < result) result = c; return result;`?  This gives you the same result and has in total as many evaluations as your first if-condition. Similary the "verbose" option of this answer: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/58749/50461

Comment: you're wasting time calculating an expression again and again if the previous conditions are false

Comment: Alternative approach that handles the boundary condition in which n1 == n2 == n3 for finding the minimum:

        // assume n1 is the minimum for now
        int min = n1;
  
  // replace min with n2 if it is smaller
        if(n2 < min)
        {
            min = n2;
        }
  
  // replace min with n3 if it is smaller
        if(n3 < min)
        {
            min = n3;
        }
  
        System.out.println(min);

Answer (score 57, accepted):

> To me it looks pretty readable

To me it doesn't.

---

## Bugs:

The following method calls **all incorrectly print `0`:**

```
System.out.println(min(3, 2, 2));
System.out.println(min(3, 3, 3));
System.out.println(min(1, 3, 3));
System.out.println(min(4, 2, 4));
```

This is because, when taking a look at your original code, it is overly complicated.

```
if( a < b && a < c && b < c) result = a ;
else if( a < b && a < c && b > c) result = a ;
```

Does it really matter if `b < c` or `b > c`? No, it doesn't here. And if `b == c` then neither of these current ones would be true which does the `return 0`. **So that's a giant bug waiting to happen.**

So those two first if's should be shortened into:

```
if (a <= b && a <= c) return a;
```

Note that I'm using `<=` here so that the case of all three having the same value gets handled correctly. Now also there's an early return so we don't need all these `else`.

---

If we group the rest of your statements according to what they return, we have for `return b`:

```
else if( a > b && a < c && b < c) result = b ;
else if( a > b && b < c && a > c) result = b ;
```

Which, if we always use `b` as the first operand and completely ignore whether or not `a < c` or `a > c` (and again, `a == c` is not handled here) we get:

```
if (b <= a && b <= c) return b;
```

Doing the same for `c`:

```
if (c <= a && c <= b) return c;
```

As one of `a`, `b` or `c` really *has* to be smallest, you can throw an exception if neither one of them is:

```
public static int min(int a, int b, int c) {
     if (a <= b && a <= c) return a;
     if (b <= a && b <= c) return b;
     if (c <= a && c <= b) return c;
     throw new AssertionError("No value is smallest, how did that happen?");
}
```

Or, if you don't like that exception:

```
public static int min(int a, int b, int c) {
     if (a <= b && a <= c) return a;
     if (b <= a && b <= c) return b;
     return c;
}
```

This is in my opinion *significantly* better than your original version.

However, I would recommend Pimgd's solution, either an array or using chained `Math.min`.

Comment: Personally, if I went your way, I would just return `c` after finding that neither `a` nor `b` is the correct answer.

Comment: @Pimgd Yes, that'd also be a satisfactory solution. But when using an exception, you are really sure that `c` really has to be the smallest.

Comment: I'm just curious, but do you know of a situation where it would be possible for neither of the 3 to be smallest? I know in ActionScript you can get this with NaN (comparing with NaN is always false)...

Comment: @Pimgd No, I don't know of such a situation, but *if such a situation exists* (highly unlikely) it will throw an Exception instead of *incorrectly* returning `3`.

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg,  I feel ashamed, but you are right - I dont' need to check for other values... my logic was flawed

Comment: A comparison with NaN will always return false. Thus if two numbers are NaN you should probably return NaN as well instead of `c` as you did in the last code example. An exception would be ok I guess - depending on the context. so "how did that happen?" -> simply because `!(a > b)` does not imply `a <= b`.

Comment: Oh wait. `int`.... leave it as it is then, but note that NaNs can happen with floating point numbers...

Comment: If we get past `if (a <= b && a <= c) return a;` without returning `a`, we can safely assert that `a > min(a, b, c)`, or equivalently, `min(b, c) == min(a, b, c)`.  Therefore, we can simplify `if (b <= a && b <= c) return b;` to `if (b <= c) return b;`, or even do away with `return c;` and just do `return b <= c ? b : c;`

Comment: I usually avoid having multiple returns.  I like to be able to set a breakpoint on the return statement and see the returned value.  For that same reason, I like if's to have a condition and statement on separate lines.

Answer (score 73):

For these things we have `java.lang.Math`:

```
public static int min(final int a, final int b, final int c){
    return Math.min(a, Math.min(b, c));
}
```

Wow, look how short it is!

But it's 3 numbers today, it's 10 tomorrow.
As an alternative, how about an array?

```
public static int min(int... numbers){
    if (numbers.length == 0){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Can't determine smallest element in an empty set");
    }
    int smallest = numbers[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < numbers.length; i++){
        smallest = Math.min(smallest, numbers[i]);
    }
    return smallest;
}
```

I'd use the `java.lang.Math` solution, it's very short, and very readable.

Comment: For your 1st case there is `java.util.Collections.min()`. However, it works on collections.

Comment: I actually went looking for that, but then I realized I was using an array. Yet another possibility to use! It uses a `Comparator` though, so even with `Integer` objects you end up writing some wrapper.

Comment: Your second example (with the array) seems more complicated than what I have (see my answer).

Comment: @Ryan That's because it's \$O(n)\$ and not \$O(2n)\$. It's faster because it doesn't first cast it into a list. Additionally, it doesn't autobox and unbox the `int`'s, so that's another performance issue mitigated.

Comment: @Pimgd While you are correct that it has less performance, I think that readability and maintainability should be taken into account.

Comment: @Pimgd \$O(n) = O(2n)\$.

Answer (score 16):

I'd suggest using ternary operator, which is quite readable for me:

```
public static int min(int a, int b, int c) {
     return (a < b) ? (a < c) ? a
                              : c
                    : (b < c) ? b
                              : c;
}
```

However, if you prefer ifs:

```
public static int min(int a, int b, int c) {
    int min = a;
    if (min > b) min = b;
    if (min > c) min = c;
    return min;
}
```

In both cases only two comparisons will be performed.

Comment: I disagree, that ternary operator is not readable. Your other method is perfectly fine though.

Comment: @Kao Perhaps, but having even a small amount of unreadable/unmaintainable code in an application only spawns more of the same. I'd prefer to keep my code clean, easily maintainable and very readable. Even if more readable code leads to a small performance drop, I'll gladly take that hit since it leads to more robust code.

Comment: @FreeAsInBeer I agree, but trust me - there are worse practices (*returns back to traversing through 24-level nested `if` statement*)

Comment: @KyleHale actually for the scope of the problem I definitely agree with FreeAsInBeer. A ternary itself is already the less readable approach, and then unintuitively creating additional confusion like in the first, by nesting them, enrages me...

Comment: I've taken the liberty of reformatting the ternary expression to make it slightly more readable, though I still find the if-if version easier to understand.

Comment: The second is also unreadable. I have to think really hard when you use > in a min operation.

Answer (score 11):

Here is my idea: use an optional parameter, and use built-in libraries. Much clearer and simpler to understand. This works with 3 parameters, but also works with any # of parameters.

```
public static Integer min(Integer... numbers) {
    if (numbers.length == 0) return 0;
    // wanted this: assert numbers.length > 0;, but does not work
    return Collections.min(Arrays.asList(numbers));
}
```

Calling with:

```
System.out.println(min(2,1,3));
```

gives 1.

I tried to find a solution using generics but cannot get it to work.

**Edit**: Use `IllegalArgumentException` (thanks @SimonAndréForsberg!):

```
public static Integer min(Integer... numbers) {
    if (numbers.length == 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot have 0 arguments, i.e. min()");
    return Collections.min(Arrays.asList(numbers));
}
```

**Edit**: The reason this solution works is that `Integer... numbers` allows for the program calling it to specify any number of arguments (even 0), and inside `min` here, it is treated as an array, which we can find the minimum of that array using `Collections.min` and `Arrays.asList`.

Answer (score 10):

I don't think it's really readable, as it conveys a lot of logic, which is simply unneeded.

Also you should, according to most of the common Java coding standards, not be placing `{` on its newline, also there should be no blank space between `result` and `;` in `return result ;`

I would suggest following, though it needs Java 8:

```
public static int min(final int first, final int... others) {
    return IntStream.concat(IntStream.of(first), IntStream.of(others))
        .min()
        .getAsInt();
}
```

This way you cover the following:

- You allow an arbitrary amount of integers to be passed to the method.
- You get the `min()` in a clear way, using Java 8 streams, it checks the minimum somehow.
- Because you know you have at least one result, you can safety get the value from the `OptionalInt`.

One minor nitpick is that the `IntStream.concat(IntStream.of(first), IntStream.of(others))` to construct an `IntStream` is rather ugly.

Comment: Where do you get the coding standards from to say the braces should be on the same line as the method signature?

Comment: @Pimgd - I need to collect the three typical code-style guides in to one place, probably the Java tag wiki